# Difference between @constant and @view on a smartcontract function

Tags: vyper

I am reading some vyper projects on github.

I have seen 2 attributes on the line before the function name: @constant and @view

According to documentation, this 2 attributes are saying the function may not change the state of the blockchain.

But what is the differences between this 2 attributes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is the differences between this 2 attributes ?

Nothing :-)

`@constant` was renamed to `@view` in issue [#2040](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/issues/2040).

(See release notes for Vyper [0.2.1](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release-notes.html?highlight=constant#v0-2-1).)